# Linear operator is not isomorphic proof

Tags: functional-analysis

For $X=Y=l_1$ consider the linear operator $T((x_n))=(x_1,-x_2,x_3,-x_4,...)$ and answer the following: Is $T$ surjective, injective, isometric or isomorphic? Find out if T is continuous and it attains its norm.

I arrived at the conclusion that $T$ is surjective, isometric and $\|T\|=1,$ therefore it is also continuous, which should be the correct conclusion, however, $T$ also isn't isomorphic, which I can't see why, with the following reasoning:

Let $x,y\in l_2$ such that $x\neq y,T(x)=T(y)$, then $$0=T(x)-T(y)=(x_1-y_1,y_2-x_2,x_3-y_3,y_4-x_4,...)$$ and therefore $$x_n=y_n,\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \implies x=y$$
and thus $T$ is also injective. According to the Banach theorem, we know that $l_1$ is Banach space and $T$ is continuous, surjective and injective and therefore it is isomorphic.

Comment: Why would it not be an isomorphism? (hint: it is an isomorphism)

Comment: Thank you, I'm checking because the lecture notes don't mention anything about it being an isomorphism and therefore I assumed that it's not an isomorphism

Comment: Some language you're using incorrectly: the map is a linear operator or linear transformation, but it is not a linear functional; linear functionals output numbers rather than vectors. It is incorrect to call a map "isomorphic" because it is an isomorphism; instead, two spaces are called "isomorphic" if there is an isomorphism defined from one to the other.

Comment: All the properties follow from the fact that $T$ is an isometry and $T^2=I.$

Comment: @BenGrossman Thank you for clarifying, I have corrected the post.